# How to Inject a Service with Parameterized constructor to a Component - Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Create a Service class (CourseService):

Service class with Parameterized constructor

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

  @Injectable()
  export class CourseService {

  constructor(private name?:string) { }

  getName() : string{
    return "Service Name is"+ this.name;
  }

}
```

Injecting the service to Component.

In Provider its already injected like this

```
  providers: [
    CourseService
  ]
```

Created the component class

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { CourseService } from '../../services/course.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-course',
      templateUrl: './course.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
    })
    export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private courseService: CourseService) { }

      ngOnInit() {

        let serviceName = this.courseService.getName();
      }

    }
```

Browser console error:

```
 AppComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[CourseService]: 
   StaticInjectorError[CourseService]: 
   NullInjectorError: No provider for CourseService!
   at _NullInjector.get (core.js:993)
   at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
   at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
   at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
   at resolveToken (core.js:1281)
   at tryResolveToken (core.js:1223)
   at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1094)
   at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10878)
   at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:12110)
   at resolveDep (core.js:12608)
```

How to inject this service in the component?

Comment: Parameters of type string cannot be injected from the container. Just make it a local variable. Only provided services can be injected. I assume `CourseServicesService` is a typo above, yes?

Answer (score 7):

It's impossible by design. Angular's injectables are shared (there is only one instance) for whole scope where the service has been defined. Passing different parameters in constructor for the same instance just would not make sense. If you need many instances of your service, you can create it by yourself, just do:

```
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {
  private courseService: CourseService;
  constructor() { 
    this.courseService = new CourseService('someName');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let serviceName = this.courseService.getName();
  }
}
```